# TeXstudio scripts – internal viewer

Tags: texstudio, scripts

I need to make a macro script that would "press" `Fit to Width` button in the TeXstudio's internal viewer.

I found that viewer object is called `pdfs[0]`, but, unfortunately, on the wiki page there are no list of methods of this object.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching a bit in the source code (see [here](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/blob/master/src/pdfviewer/PDFDocument.cpp)), I found that `pdfs` object *may be* related to `PDFDocument`.

From [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/discussion/907840/thread/e044b047/#805d) I also found a script involving the pdf viewer.

Then I've made several attempts and I've figured out the solution:

```
pdfs[0].widget().fitWidth();
```

Comment: Thank you so much!